# Create Object Array in foreach Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an Array with these values, I need to create a loop on these values to return in alasql like this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/11gd86nx/5/

```
var data = {
  "business": [
{
  "order_contents": [
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 85,
      "name": "product 3",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 84,
      "name": "product 2",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 83,
      "name": "product 1",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    },
    {
      "id": 84,
      "name": "product 2",
      "price": "1.99",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": "1.99",
      "ingredients": [],
      "extras": []
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};
```

here's my code..

```
    info.orderByChild("data").startAt("08/04/2017").endAt("12/06/2017").on('value', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(item) {

           jsonObj = {
              "business": [
            {
              "order_contents": [
                {
                  "id": itemVal['id'],
                  "name": itemVal['name'],
                  "price": itemVal['price'],
                  "quantity": itemVal['quantity'],
                  "total": "itemVal['total']
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

its not creating an array, only the last value..

can someone help me?

Comment: If this is Firebase-related, please tag it as such.

Comment: ok, its tagged! thanks

Comment: You're overwriting the same variable (`jsonObj`) on each iteration, that's why it ends up with the last item. Where do you define `jsonObj` and what are you using it for?

Comment: i define as var jsonObj = [];   and I use for alasql to create a 'database' of this object

Comment: @sealabr Unfortunately your question has not aged well.   jsFiddle sample is no longer available. It's unclear the return type of the startAt and endAt functions. By tailoring the payload and functions 'just enough to recreate the error questions will get faster responses and have greater longevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your array in the beginning and add each object to it later on in your loop:

```
var result = { business: [] }; // PLACEHOLDER
var jsonObj;
info.orderByChild("data").startAt("08/04/2017").endAt("12/06/2017").on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
            jsonObj = {
                "order_contents": [
                    {
                        "id": itemVal['id'],
                        "name": itemVal['name'],
                        "price": itemVal['price'],
                        "quantity": itemVal['quantity'],
                        "total": "itemVal['total']
                    }
                ]
            };
            result.business.push(jsonObj);  // ADDING EACH OBJECT TO YOUR ARRAY
        });
    });
```

Comment: ok but its returns Array [ Object, Object, Object......] need to be .....Object { business: Array[1] }

Comment: Hm wait, but you have an object like that already? Your `data` variable is structured in that way - `Object { business: Array[1] }`...

Comment: yeah I need to create this object 'jsonObj' (in foreach) exactly like this 'data' ..because this 'data' is an example.

Comment: I updated my answer... Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: "never define variables inside a loop when possible" only pertains to regular `for` and `while` loops as they don't scope the variables properly. Defining variables in callbacks, as with `forEach`, is perfectly fine and definitely preferable to overwriting a variable in the outside closure.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map the items in `snapshot` to a new array, so instead of using the `forEach` method, use the `map` method and the resulting array it returns:

```
  jsonObj = snapshot.map(function(item) {
    return {
      "business": [
        {
          "order_contents": [
            {
              "id": item['id'],
              "name": item['name'],
              "price": item['price'],
              "quantity": item['quantity'],
              "total": item['total']
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```